# Is there a way to instruct bazel to list all the test targets it has found without building or testing them?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have 200 subdirectories and I need to find how many how many has test targes and only build them instead of building all. is there a way?

Is there a way to instruct bazel to list all the test targets it has found without building or testing them? then I will create loop to build only those that has test targets.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the tests only by using the flag `--build_tests_only` which will  cause bazel only to build the dependencies of the test targets.

Docs are here: https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#build-tests-only

Comment: but I want first identify also what are the directories that have them defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think `bazel test $(bazel query siblings(tests(//...)))` is what you're looking for.

[bazel query](https://bazel.build/query/guide) can provide what you're looking for. `bazel query tests(//...)` will show all your test targets. `bazel query tests(//...) --output=packages` will list all the packages with tests, and then you can count them externally. `bazel query siblings(tests(//...))` will list all the targets in packages containing tests.

Note that Bazel uses [packages](https://bazel.build/concepts/build-ref#packages), which are related to directories, but not quite the same. A package is a directory with a BUILD file plus all of its subdirectories that do not contain BUILD files. If all directories contain BUILD files, then packages and directories are equivalent.